# Stringify single and double quotes

Tags: json, stringify

With the following code I am creating an object to pass to a webservice. The single quote seems to be handled with a replace in the stringify before the object is passed to the service, but I don't know how to modify the double quote. If I inspect the Program.Comments field it would show the string like \"Word". This will cause an error in the stringify.

Is this an incorrect way to use the stringify for Json

```
 Program = new Object();
 Program.Field1 = $('#txtField1').val();
 Program.Field2 = $('#ddlField2').val();
 Program.Field3 = $('#lblField3').text();
 Program.Field4 = $('#ddlField4').val();
 Program.Field5 = $('#ddlField5').val();
 Program.Field6 = $('#ddlField6').val();

 // This field may contain both single and double quotes
 Program.Comments = $('#txtComments').val();

 Program.Field7 = $('#txtField7').val();
 Program.Field8 = $('input[name=chbField8]').is(':checked');

 // This will fix the issue of a single quote
 vdata = JSON.stringify(Program).replace(/'/g, "\\'");d
```

Comment: Treat JSONification as opaque. That is, don't attempt to modify JSON strings. If we trust that `JSON.stringify` returns valid JSON (it does), then the issue is on the receiving end not parsing JSON correctly.

Comment: I have a deserialize function that the json is passed to and this is where it seems to break down. The string would look like:      {"ProgramComments":"It's in "Current"","ProgramStartDate":"8/5/2006","ProgramActive":true}

Comment: That's not a possible value for `JSON.stringify` to produce -- it's invalid JSON. Did you overwrite the stringify method to make it produce garbage JSON?
Also, did you write the deseralization method yourself?

Comment: Here's normal JSON.stringify output:
`Program = new Object(); Program.foo = "Bar's \"Baz\" Quux"; JSON.stringify(Program)`
=> `"{"foo":"Bar's \"Baz\" Quux"}"`

Comment: If I remove the .replace function, the stringify will fail, and when inspecting the Program object, the Program.Comments is declared a non json string? So why will the stringify not handle my above object Program.Comments that may contain both an apostrophe and double quotes? Thank is my problem.

Comment: Again, I'm confident JSON.stringify produces good output, regardless of whether the data it serializes contains single or double quotes. I think your problem lies in the deserialization method. What are you using for deserialization?

Comment: The following is what I am seeing from stringify just before it enters the deserialize the type {"ProgramComments":"It is "Current"", (notice the spare")
"ProgramStartDate":"8/5/2006",
"ProgramActive":true}. The ProgramComments has no escape characters around the word "Current" when it should, based on your above description.

Comment: Something is happening to the data along the way because that's not valid JSON. Can you verify that JSON.stringify generates valid JSON?

Comment: I found a piece of code for replace(/(['"])/g,"\\$1") that seems to work. Thank you for your persistence on this.